# Lighting is off

Tags: lighting

I've been following Donut tutorial part 6, and in terms of light settings, me and Blender Guru are using the same, but seems like my rendered donut is.. you can't even tell that it's a donut. Did i mess up along the way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, the stregth of your light is pretty low, what does it give if you increase it?

Comment: @moonboots it seems fine but the difference is quite big, what bothers me is that 20w seem to be enough for him, but not for me :( I wonder why, when i've been following carefully the tutorial

Comment: Is he using a Point lignt? Also, is yours far away from the objects? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It would have been great if you included the light object in the screenshot so we could see the distance - maybe even the XYZ values of the location. Andrew moves it all in all about 0.96 m off the world center. That is not very much - where is your light? If I use his settings and place the light where he does, it looks the same on a small torus like in the tutorial. If I leave the point light at its default location from the startup file (that's 7.24 m from the center) and set it to 20.2 W, it looks like your result.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you! Seems like this was the issue, i moved the light object closer to the donut and it seems like there's proper shadows now, however another problem occurred where the render is really pixelated. What could be the cause?

Comment: @Mono That depends on how it looks and how you've set up the render, it can have many different reasons. However the comments section is not for solving multiple problems, better post a proper new question with screenshots of the issue and the render settings.